# After pip installing uWSGI there's no /etc/uwsgi/ directory - how can I use apps-enabled?

Tags: django, ubuntu, pip, uwsgi, apt-get

I've been using `apt-get install uwsgi` to install uWSGI for my Django application. Today, I realized I needed a feature that's not available until uWSGI 1.1, and Ubuntu 12.04.1 doesn't have anything after 1.0.x, at least according to my `apt-get install uwsgi=1.1` attempt. So, I used:

```
pip install http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-lts.tar.gz
```

After doing so, I get a message prescribing the use of `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi` to launch the program. I'm not a guru when it comes to compiling from source, but my understanding is that when you do so, nothing will be changed in the `/etc/` directory. Is this correct? If not, why don't I have a `/etc/uwsgi/` directory and, more specifically, a `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/` directory? Should I simply create the directories when installing uWSGI from source? I was hesitant to do so, considering there is no mention of this in the docs (I don't want something that accidentally works, etc.).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sorry for this very late reply, but maybe this will help people who'll find this answer in the future:

To get `/etc/uwsgi` etc, you need to install the uwsgi package from Debian or Ubuntu (whatever you are using) by running `aptitutde install uwsgi`. However this will by default probably install an ancient version of uwsgi! The uwsgi binary is placed in `/usr/bin/uwsgi` when installing uwsgi this way.

To get the latest version, *also* install uwsgi using pip using `pip install -U uwsgi`, which (on my Ubuntu system at least) will put the uwsgi binary in `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi` then go do the following:

`cd /usr/bin/`

`mv uwsgi uwsgi-old`

`ln -s /usr/local/bin/uwsgi uwsgi`

Alternatively: edit the uwsgi init script and edit the `DAEMON="/usr/bin/uwsgi"` appropriately.

Et voila: "debianism" (full init scripts, etc) *and* the latest uwsgi binary!

Comment: Right, but the new uwsgi is not reading from /etc/uwsgi... Where does the pip version read from?

Comment: Crazy how hard this was to find for how relevant it still is. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

/etc/uwsgi and friends is a 'debianism'. The uWSGI project is all about the sysadmin taste, so if you like the /etc/uwsgi approach just create the directory, drop config files in it and start the uWSGI Emperor to manage instances.

Comment: Thanks roberto - do you know whether or not there are any other issues / differences caused by using `pip install uwsgi` vs `apt-get install uwsgi`?

Comment: the debian package is modular, so you need to load required plugins in your config. When you install from pip a monolithic binary with the python plugin embedded in the core is installed