# Flask+NGINX+UWSGI on Google Cloud Compute Engine gives 502 bad gateway

Tags: python, nginx, flask, google-compute-engine, uwsgi

I'm trying to set up Pybossa (webapp built with Flask) on an NGINX server running on Google Cloud (following this tutorial, for reference). I think there is something wrong with the virtual host file I'm using since as soon as I enable it the server returns 502 bad gateway. The Google Compute Engine VM instance is running Debian 8.

The full hosts file is here:

```html
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name  _;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    # change that to your pybossa directory
    root /home/pybossa/pybossa;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
if (-f /home/pybossa/pybossa/503.html) {
    return 503;
}
error_page 503 @maintenance;
location / { try_files $uri @pybossa; }
location @pybossa {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock;
}
location  /static {

            # change that to your pybossa static directory
            alias /home/pybossa/pybossa/pybossa/themes/default/static;

            autoindex on;
            expires max;
        }

location ~ /api/app {
        rewrite ^/api/app /api/project$1 permanent;
}

location ~ /app {
        rewrite ^/app(.*) /project$1 permanent;
}

error_page 503 @maintenance;

location @maintenance {
    if ($uri !~ ^/static/) {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
        }
}
}
```

And the uwsgi config file:

```html
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/pybossa.sock
chmod-socket = 666
chdir = /home/pybossa/pybossa
pythonpath = ..
virtualenv = /home/pybossa/pybossa/env
module = run:app
cpu-affinity = 1
processes = 2
threads = 2
stats = /tmp/pybossa-stats.sock
buffer-size = 65535
```

I had initially set up my own NGINX server, which didn't work. Now I'm running it in an NGINX server deployed by Google cloud, which works fine until I enable the virtual hosts file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/.

The `/var/log/nginx/error.log` contains the following:

```html
2017/08/16 21:53:30 [alert] 439#0: *21 open socket #13 left in connection 4
2017/08/16 21:53:30 [alert] 439#0: *21 open socket #13 left in connection 4
2017/08/16 21:53:30 [alert] 439#0: aborting
2017/08/16 21:53:32 [crit] 16744#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server: _, reques
t: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 21:54:13 [crit] 16744#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server: _, reques
t: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 21:54:14 [crit] 16744#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server: _, reques
t: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 21:54:14 [crit] 16744#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server: _, reques
t: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 21:54:35 [crit] 16744#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server: _, reques
t: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 21:54:36 [crit] 16744#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server: _, reques
t: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 21:54:37 [crit] 16744#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server: _, reques
t: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 21:54:51 [crit] 16744#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server: _, reques
t: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
```

I'm new to web app development and haven't used Flask or NGINX before. Appreciate any help I can get.

UPDATE: After fixing the issue where uwsgi wasn't running, now error log says

```html
2017/08/16 23:53:27 [alert] 23944#0: *26 open socket #7 left in connection 3
2017/08/16 23:53:27 [alert] 23944#0: aborting
2017/08/16 23:53:30 [error] 24536#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server:
 _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 23:53:30 [error] 24536#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server:
 _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 23:53:31 [error] 24536#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server:
 _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 23:53:31 [error] 24536#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server:
 _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 23:53:31 [error] 24536#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server:
 _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 23:54:29 [error] 24536#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server:
 _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
2017/08/16 23:54:30 [error] 24536#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.107.113.211, server:
 _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock:", host: "35.184.197.200"
```

Comment: Youn mention "following this tutorial, for reference", but there is no link. What was the tutorial?

Comment: `connect() to x.sock failed`, such message points to SELinux package is installed on your server instance which by default prohibits network connection between webserver and upstream server. Further read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501111/python-djangonginxuwsgi-502-bad-gateway/55855442#55855442

Answer (score 0):

The log say **No such file or directory** is because you don't have set up    the socket in your `Nginx config`, try to add it, something like this:

```
 location / {
            proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pybossa.sock
```

Comment: The socket is set in the uwsgi config file. I edited the post to add that. 

Part of the problem was that uwsgi wasn't running because it didn't get install properly, this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965555/after-pip-installing-uwsgi-theres-no-etc-uwsgi-directory-how-can-i-use-apps explained how to get it running. Now uwsgi is running and it is giving a 500 internal server error.

Comment: and when I add the socket to the nginx config nginx fails to restart

Answer (score 0):

Check the uwsgi error logs. It should say, why it's failing or returning 500. Also, double check that the socket is created with the proper privileges, so nginx can connect to it.